# Many-to-many relationship simplification

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many, data-modeling

Consider the following two tables:

```
Messages
MessageId (PK)
Text  

Languages
LanguageId (PK)
Language
```

There is a many-to-many relationship between the Messages and Languages tables (i.e each Message can have multiple Languages, each Language can be shared by multiple Messages).  To that end, I've added the following junction table:

```
Messages_Languages
MessageId (PK)(FK)
LanguageId (PK)(FK)
```

However, it seems somewhat unnecessary as the Language is fundamentally a property of the message.  What is the advantage of use the Messages_Languages table above instead of just adding the LanguageId as a foreign key to the Messages table? (seen below)

```
Messages  
MessageId (PK)
LanguageId (PK)(FK)
Text
```

It seems to accomplish the same thing with one less table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to accomplish the same thing...

No. The junction table models many-to-many, while FK models one-to-many.

So the question is not which is better, but which do you *need*?

Comment: Just adding the languageid to the messages table does what I need.  However, I'm basically not understanding why I'm able to model this many-to-many relationship using that method, when typically modeling such a relationship requires a junction table.

Comment: Why do you think that you are modeling many-to-many with just a FK? In this situation, a message can have just one language, making this a "one (language) to many (messages)" relationship.

Comment: Basically the whole point of my post is that the solution you pick depends on your requirements, and we cannot define your requirements for you. If you need one message to be in multiple languages (e.g. multiple translations), then you need many-to-many (junction table). If given message can be in only one language at a time, one-to-many is what you need (FK).

Comment: Thanks, I get it!  It looks like I was misunderstanding the nature of the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good simple example.  Based on your simple example it is better to add LanguageID as a property to the table as you are correct: it is really just a property.  Presumably there is a fixed number of languages and the users of your application are not adding new languages as they use your application.

Whether this holds true as you further develop the application is another question.  Perhaps it will make sense to have a separate table if you add the concept of a message version or some other additional column.

Answer (score 0):

It's not matter of being able to do something but if it's right thing to do. 
Ask yourself:

> is single message going to be connected with multiple languages and
>   language can be connected to many messages?

This is many-to-many relationship and you should have junction table for it.

If you only need to provide only one language for a single message then use language id as an attribute for message. This is called one-to-many relationship.

To show you difference between those two on some numbers:

In table `Messages_Languages` you can have rows:

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
```

On last table:

```
Messages  
MessageId (PK)
LanguageId (PK)(FK)
Text
```

you'll be able to put:

```
1,1
2,3
3,2
```